# UIHostingController not resizing on autororation under certain conditions

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, autorotate, uihostingcontroller

I see `UIHostingController` hosting a SwiftUI view which is presented modally. The problem I see is it doesn't resize on autorotation if the `modalPresentationStyle` is set to `overCurrentContext`.

```
  let promptHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: promptView)
  promptHostingController.isModalInPresentation = true
  promptHostingController.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
  promptHostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
  self.present(promptHostingController, animated: animated)
```

Setting it to any other value such as `overFullScreen` solves the problem. Buy wanted to know why it fails to resize with `overCurrentContext`?

Comment: Nothing in the documentation of `overCurrentContext` says that the view would resize to fit the whole screen. The documentation of `overFullScreen`, however, *does* say it will cover the whole screen.

Comment: Try to add this line  self.definesPresentationContext = true after
 promptHostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the documentation of [`overCurrentContext`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overcurrentcontext) says that the presented view would resize to fit the whole screen. It doesn't mention anything about the size of the presented view at all:

> A presentation style where the content is displayed over another view controller’s content.

The documentation also says:

> So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.

This is exactly the case here - you did not write code that resizes the view when the screen is rotated, so the view "does not fill the screen" (let alone "opaque content") after the device is rotated.

The documentation of [`overFullScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/overfullscreen), however, does say it will "cover" the whole screen.

> A view presentation style in which the presented view covers the screen.

Note the different choice of words here - "cover" as opposed to just "over".

---

Anyway, if you want it to cover the view controller that `definesPresentationContext`, you can add auto layout constraints to the view yourself.

```
// here I'm assuming "view" is the view you want to cover
let host = UIHostingController(rootView: ...)
host.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
host.sizingOptions = [.intrinsicContentSize]
host.presentationController?.delegate = self
host.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
present(host, animated: true) { [self] in
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        host.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        host.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
        host.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        host.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

You should add the constraints after the hosting controller is presented, which is why I put `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` in the completion handler of `present`. Before that, the presented view is not yet in the view hierarchy yet.

Also, use [`intrinsicContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uihostingcontrollersizingoptions/intrinsiccontentsize) as the sizing option. As its documentation says, you should use this when you layout the hosting view with AutoLayout.